# Moving feature branch parent to latest master [git]

Tags: git

Currently I have the following git graph

```
A - B - C - D        master
     \
      E              feature
```

Is there a way to move the parent of commit **E** to be **D**

```
A - B - C - D        master
             \
              E      feature
```

Note: I'm aware I can merge master **into** the feature branch, but I'm hoping to find another solution

Note: I use the feature branch to update a single npm package. Sometimes I have conflict with lock file when I created a pull request. So maybe moving the parent of a feature branch could solve this.

Comment: You could try a rebase: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git rebase master feature
```

This checks out master then applies each commit on feature to master. Since commits are immutable and the hash of a commit includes the sha of the parent commit, a different parent will create a new commit.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: So it's more like apply changes from master into feature. 

Instead of moving parent of commit 'E' to commit 'D'.

Comment: @Clumsy-Coder not always. There are times it uses a three-way merge.